# Increment Multiple Timestamp Values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table where i have a default value for the timestamp, e.g. 2013-06-15 12:00:00. There are at least 150 records with that value. Now I want to increment each of these timestamps by 1 second, taking into account that after 59 seconds, next value is next minute. Is this possible? Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: Just increment them.  The timestamps don't care about the minute transitions; minutes are a display phenomenon.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have tried using date_add() but it gives ALL the records the same value. I need to have unique values for each record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another simple approach: (@kordirko, Thank you for your sqlfiddle)

```
SET @serial:=1;
UPDATE table1 SET t = t + INTERVAL (@serial:=@serial+1) SECOND;
```

You can test here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5cbe/1

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Assumming that the table has unique `id` column, this query can do this task:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1, (
   SELECT t1.id, count(*) cnt
   FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
   GROUP BY t1.id
) t2
SET t1.t = t1.t + interval t2.cnt second
WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6ef9b/1